# Why do I get ( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg ); when posting to a custom rails route and passing a param via AJAX?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I have a Rails application with a custom route to my `SaleQualifiers` controller. The purpose of this route is to find `SaleQualifiers` that have a specific `sale_stage` and display them in a panel via AJAX. The buttons, routes and panels all work perfectly well (i.e. the action behaves as expected and the correct results are rendered), but my RSpec tests don't like it as the console logs the error: `Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg` which stops the test from running.

Presumably I ought to fix this error anyway, but I've gotten stuck as I don't know why it's coming through.

The new action/route I've defined is called `prospect qualifiers`:

```
class SaleQualifiersController < ApplicationController
 before_action :set_sale_qualifier, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
 def prospect_qualifiers
  @sales_opportunity = SalesOpportunity.find_by(id: session[:sales_opportunity_id])
  @stage = params[:sale_stage]
  ... etc - just picks out the right SaleQualifier(s) to render
end
```

The link_to my action:

```
<%= link_to stage, prospect_qualifiers_sale_qualifiers_path(:sale_stage => stage), :remote => true, data: { disable_with: "Loading...", toggle: 'tab' } %>
```

This is rendered from `<%= render partial: 'shared/tabs', collection: @stages, as: :stage %>` this partial - basically creating a link for each stage in the @stages collection and passing that as a param to the controller action.

The js.erb file called by the Controller is called Modal_Form (just inherited this name):

```
$('#qualifier_tabs').html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/tabs', collection: @stages, as: :stage %>");
$('#qualifier_panel').html("<%= j render :partial => 'shared/panel', collection: @stages, as: :stage %>");
$(function () {
    $('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
      pickTime: false,
      dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    });
  });
```

This is just updating the tabs partial to highlight the one that was clicked, then rendering in the right SaleQualifiers to the `#qualifier_panel`.

An example output of the logs from clicking this shows the following:

```
Started GET "/sale_qualifiers/prospect_qualifiers?sale_stage=Budget" for 127.0.0.1 at 2016-04-05 17:30:23 +0800
Processing by SaleQualifiersController#prospect_qualifiers as JS
  Parameters: {"sale_stage"=>"Budget"}
  SalesOpportunity Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "sales_opportunities".* FROM "sales_opportunities"  WHERE "sales_opportunities"."id" = 87  ORDER BY close_date ASC LIMIT 1
   (0.6ms)  SELECT "questions"."sale_stage" FROM "questions"   ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC
  SaleQualifier Load (0.9ms)  SELECT sale_qualifiers.* FROM sale_qualifiers INNER JOIN questions ON questions.id = sale_qualifiers.question_id WHERE has_answer = 'true' AND sales_opportunity_id = 87 AND questions.sale_stage = 'Budget' 
  Question Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "questions".* FROM "questions"  WHERE "questions"."sale_stage" = 'Budget'  ORDER BY "questions"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
  Rendered shared/_tabs.html.erb (2.7ms)
  Rendered shared/_panel.html.erb (0.9ms)
  Rendered sale_qualifiers/modal_form.js.erb (10.7ms)
Completed 200 OK in 25ms (Views: 15.4ms | ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

Which is fine - it works perfectly, renders the right info into the panel and is as expected. But the console in the browser shows:

```
Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: 

/sale_qualifiers/prospect_qualifiers?sale_stage=Budget


throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );
```

Is this some syntax error on my part (the normal source of these bloody JQuery errors), or am I doing something fundamentally wrong by passing a param into the AJAX submission along the prospect_qualifier_sale_qualifiers_path?

Any help would be welcome.

**Edit - adding Tabs and Qualifier panel**

```
<% if stage == @stage %>
<li class="active"><%= link_to stage, prospect_qualifiers_sale_qualifiers_path(:sale_stage => stage), :remote => true, data: { disable_with: "Loading...", toggle: 'tab' } %></li>
<% else %>
    <li><%= link_to stage, prospect_qualifiers_sale_qualifiers_path(:sale_stage => stage), :remote => true, data: { disable_with: "Loading...", toggle: 'tab' } %></li>
<% end %>
```

Panel:

```
<% if stage ==  @stage %>


<div class="tab-pane active" id='<%=stage %>'>
        <table class="table table-striped display responsive no-wrap">
                 <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>Question</th>
                     <th>Answer</th>
                     <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
                 </thead>
                 <tbody>
                 <!-- if a sale_qualifier exists with an answer show the following -->
                  <% @sale_qualifiers.each do |qual| %>
                  <tr>
                    <td><%= qual.question.question_text %></td>
                    <% if qual.question.answer_type == "Datetime"%>
                        <td><%= qual.answer.answer_text.to_date.readable_inspect %></td>
                    <% elsif qual.question.answer_type == "Boolean" %>
                        <% if qual.answer.answer_text == 'true'%>
                            <td>Yes</td>
                        <% elsif qual.answer.answer_text == 'false' %>
                            <td>No</td>
                        <% end %>
                    <% else %>
                        <td><%= qual.answer.answer_text %></td>
                    <% end %>
                    <td><%= link_to('edit', edit_sale_qualifier_path(qual), class: "btn btn-sm btn-warning", data: { disable_with: "Loading...", dismiss: 'modal' }, :remote => true )%></td>
                  </tr>
                  <% end %>
                  <!-- if there's no sale_qualifier with the question id then build one -->
                    <%= form_tag('/sale_qualifiers', :id => 'new_sale_qualifier', :class => 'form', method: :post, remote: true, data: { model: "sale_qualifier" }) do -%>
                        <%= fields_for :sale_qualifier do |ff| %>
                            <%= ff.hidden_field :sales_opportunity_id, :value => @sales_opportunity.id, form: "new_sale_qualifier" %>
                            <%= ff.hidden_field :question_id, :value => @question.id, form: "new_sale_qualifier" %>
                          <tr>
                            <td><%= @question.question_text %></td>
                            <td>
                              <%= ff.fields_for :answer_attributes do |answer| %>  
                                <div class="form-group">
                                  <% if @question.answer_type == 'Text Field' %>
                                    <%= answer.text_area :answer_text, :placeholder => "Enter your answer", form: "new_sale_qualifier"%>
                                  <% end %>
                                  <% if @question.answer_type == 'Datetime' %>
                                    <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker' data-date-format="YY.MM.DD">
                                      <%= answer.text_field :answer_text, class: "form-control", data: { date_format: 'YYYY/MM/DD' }, :placeholder => "YYYY/MM/DD", form: "new_sale_qualifier" %>
                                      <span class="input-group-addon">
                                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                       </span>
                                    </div>
                                  <% end %>
                                  <% if @question.answer_type == 'Boolean' %>
                                    <%= answer.select :answer_text, [['Yes', true], ['No', false]], form: "new_sale_qualifier" %>
                                  <% end %>
                                  <span class="warning-block"></span>
                                  <span class="help-block"></span>
                                 </div>
                              <% end %>
                            </td>
                            <td>
                                <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "btn btn-large btn-success", id: "sale_qualifier_submit", data: { disable_with: "Submitting..." }, autocomplete: 'off', form: "new_sale_qualifier" %>
                            </td>
                         </tr>
                        <% end %>     
                    <% end %>   
                </tbody>
            </table>
    </div>
<% else %>
    <div class="tab-pane" id='<%=stage %>'>
    </div>
<% end %>
```

I'll have a dig through this code myself too, just in case I can see where the whitespace comes from. I hate debugging things like this in Jquery.

For reference I'm using jquery-rails (3.1.2)

Comment: What's in your shared/tabs or shared/panel? There is probably some whitespace or another char that shouldn't be there.  It must start with a '<' or you will get that error. What's your jQuery version?

Comment: Thanks @RalphKing - I've added the requested info and will try and unpick the whitespace myself too. As you can see there's quite a lot of code being rendered in this partial, so that may take some time.